# Cleaner URLs for SAS Stored Process Web Application

Tags: sas

Is it possible to make a SAS Stored Process available via a clean, nicer looking URL, but still be hosted on the server?

The native URL is something like http://[yourMachineName]:8080/SASStoredProcess/do?_PROGRAM=/WebApps/MyWebApp/Foo.

I'd prefer a nicer looking URL like http://[yourMachineName]:8080/SASStoredProcess/WebApps/MyWebApp/Foo

The documentation for the overall process at http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=stpug&docsetTarget=dbgsrvlt.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en, doesn't seem to address the issue.

Comment: You might try adding url-rewriting tag to your question to get people with knowledge in that area to respond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely - yes, you can do this.  The way to do this is to use a front end framework to provide a routing facility. Or - simply host an `index.html` file at a particular folder (corresponding to the `_PROGRAM` path) on your mid-tier, then use the 'on-load' javascript event to fire `window.location.replace()` with the full path to your STP as a parameter.

Your url could then be http://[yourMachineName]:8080/WebApps/MyWebApp/Foo.

I wrote a guide to building web applications with SAS which is available [here](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings17/1091-2017.pdf), and a quick blog on the subject available [here](https://www.rawsas.com/2015/12/building-web-apps-with-sas/).

As a general point - is much more user friendly to build a nice looking UX using a modern framework such as REACT or Angular, and use that to call your SAS services as appropriate, displaying results in a myriad of ways - than to call raw SAS programs directly (for surfacing data).

Angular routing: https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in the SAS Stored Process Web Application. The SAS URL must contain the SAS folder path and name of your storedprocess.
Possible options you can do  within the Stored Process Web App are:

- Use the Folders view in the SAS Stored Process Web Application URL, so each user can navigate to the desired stored process from there:

  http://YourServer:8080/SASStoredProcess/do?_Action=index

[image: StoredProcess]

- If you have a web page or SAS Visual Analytics available to your users: you can hyperlink the SP URL to any [Text](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/stpug/62758/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0m6bfw604p33tn1ly7rbrx3ghla.htm).